# Bar chart series Showing gaps between the series

Tags: highcharts

While using the bar chart I got into a situation.
If I left a series blank or I left out some of the point of the series as blank then the chart produces gap for that series.
It can be seen from the below jsfiddle where I have removed some of the points from the New York.
Can you help me out to produce the bars without those gaps if some point in the chart series is missing ?

--http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/

```
enter code here
```

---http://jsfiddle.net/7kNCn/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now it's not possible to workaround. You can post a feature request on http://highcharts.uservoice.com